# What does a blue line indicate in Logisim?

Tags: logisim

I know dark green indicates 0, bright green indicates 1, orange indicates incompatible bit width, but what does a blue line indicate?

[image]

Comment: Oh logisim, 61C? It indicates an unknown state See: http://www.cburch.com/logisim/docs/2.1.0/guide/bundles/colors.html

Comment: @crasic: Simple answer, but that's all there is to it, so why not move it to the answer box?

Comment: @RespawnedFluff done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Blue wire indicates an unknown state, distinct from a not connected wire or error state, it means that the ALU component is not driving the output (e.g. invalid input or op-code).

Blue wire is reserved for one-bit signals, an unknown state in a multi-bit bus is not indicated via wire color but is represented by an X on any output readout.

See: [This Documentation Page](http://www.cburch.com/logisim/docs/2.1.0/guide/bundles/colors.html)